# How do i put all rows from php to the email?

Tags: php, email

I wrote a script that is supposed to select all users from the database, then select all matches they are commenting and mail it. But it only sends the last match selected.

```
require 'connection.php';
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tipuser");


foreach($query as $email){
    $username = $email['id'];
    $datumted = date("Y-m-d");
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM zapasy 
                                  WHERE komentator1 = '$username' AND datum = '$datumted' 
                                    OR komentator2 = '$username' AND datum = '$datumted'");

    while ($xx = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) { 
        $datum = $xx['datum'];
        $projekt = $xx['projekt'];

        $projektquery = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM projekt 
                                             WHERE id = '$projekt'");
        $projektpole = mysqli_fetch_array($projektquery);
        $projektx = $projektpole['name'];

        $stream = $xx['stream'];
        $tv = $xx['televize'];
        $team1 = $xx['domaci'];
        $team2 = $xx['hoste'];
        $cas = $xx['cas'];   
        $message = "$datum | $cas | $team1 v $team2 | $projektx | $stream | $tv \n";
    }

    $datex = date('d/m/Y');
    $to = $email['name'];
    $subject = "Vaše zápasy $datex";
    $headers = 'From: admin@sportsradio.cz';
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

`$message` is text that it mails I need to mail all selected matches in 1 mail.

Comment: You're overwriting `$message` instead of appending to it. Last one stays.

Comment: @kerbholz well, how can I append to it?

Comment: Using a string operator: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php.

Comment: @kerbholz well I have no idea how to use that what so ever.

Comment: Not a problem, I posted an answer, see if that helps. I added `//` comments to the lines I added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting your `$message` with every iteration of the while loop. The last one is the one you get in your mail. You should append to `$message` with every iteration.

```
require 'connection.php';
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tipuser");

foreach($query as $email){
    $message = ''; // "init" $message
    $username = $email['id'];
    $datumted = date("Y-m-d");
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM zapasy 
                                  WHERE komentator1 = '$username' AND datum = '$datumted' 
                                    OR komentator2 = '$username' AND datum = '$datumted'");

    while ($xx = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) { 
        $datum = $xx['datum'];
        $projekt = $xx['projekt'];

        $projektquery = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM projekt 
                                             WHERE id = '$projekt'");
        $projektpole = mysqli_fetch_array($projektquery);
        $projektx = $projektpole['name'];

        $stream = $xx['stream'];
        $tv = $xx['televize'];
        $team1 = $xx['domaci'];
        $team2 = $xx['hoste'];
        $cas = $xx['cas'];   
        $message .= "$datum | $cas | $team1 v $team2 | $projektx | $stream | $tv \n"; // .= appends to $message
    }

    $datex = date('d/m/Y');
    $to = $email['name'];
    $subject = "Vaše zápasy $datex";
    $headers = 'From: admin@sportsradio.cz';
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Info on string operators: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php